# How to delete large amount of data from Oracle table using separated transactions?

Tags: sql, plsql, liquibase

I need to delete about 5 millions of records from Oracle table.
Due to the performance (REDO logs) I would like to remove 100000 records per transaction, like this:

```
DECLARE
 v_limit PLS_INTEGER :=100000;

CURSOR person_deleted_cur
IS 
 SELECT rowid 
   FROM Persons p
  WHERE City = 'ABC'
   AND NOT EXISTS
               (SELECT O_Id
                  FROM Orders o
                 WHERE p.P_Id = o.P_Id);

TYPE person_deleted_nt IS TABLE OF person_deleted_cur%ROWTYPE
        INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  OPEN person_deleted_cur;
    LOOP
      FETCH person_deleted_cur 
        BULK COLLECT INTO person_deleted_nt LIMIT v_limit;

    FORALL indx IN 1 .. person_deleted_nt.COUNT 
      DELETE FROM Persons WHERE rowid=person_deleted_nt(indx);

    EXIT WHEN person_deleted_cur%NOTFOUND;

   END LOOP;

   CLOSE person_deleted_cur;
  COMMIT;
END;
```

But Liquibase runs changeSet in one transaction and rolls it back if there are any errors. Is a good habit to use *COMMIT* manifestly in Liquibase scripts?
What should be a well-written script?

Comment: Do you mean UNDO instead of REDO?  Using separate transactions would create *more* REDO, and less UNDO at one point-in-time.  But even then, how much space does 5 million PERSONS rows require?  Surely you've got at least a few GB of spare UNDO space.  Check it with a query like this: `select (maxbytes-bytes)/1024/1024/1024 gb from dba_data_files where file_name like '%UNDO%';`

Answer (score 0):

In the book "Oracle for professionals" Tom Kyte written about update in others transactions. The point is: if you can change table with one query then so do. Because one query will faster than differ transactions or plsql loop with partition delete.
Another a approach would be to use `CREATE TABLE` with `NOLOGGING` instead of `UPDATE/DELETE`. It is the best solution for a change many rows.

So create nologging table with your query, than to delete original table and recreate index, constraints and etc, than rename temp table to original table.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @jimmbraddock, but a more simple solution that is lower impact when it comes to an OLTP system might be to repeatedly run this query until it affects no more rows:

```
DELETE FROM Persons p
WHERE City = 'ABC'
AND NOT EXISTS
           (SELECT O_Id
              FROM Orders o
             WHERE p.P_Id = o.P_Id)
AND ROWNUM <= 100000;
```

The total resource usage would be higher than a single delete, and thus a single delete would still be better if your system can accommodate it, but this would be pretty robust, and with an index on persons(city,p_id) and one on orders(p_id) it should be very performant.